# scaling current time to a range in python

Tags: python, datetime, scaling

I want to scale the current time in a range. Like my start time is 08:00 hours and end time is 19:00 hours which is a 11 hr period. scaled value of my start time should be 0 and scaled value of my end time should be 11. Times like 10:00 and 10:30 should be scaled as 1 and 1.5 respectively.My code

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

start_time = '08:00'
end_time = '19:00'
```

The above code is reading the variable as strings and I'm not able to perform calculations on them. Can some one help me achieving the scaling.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change `now.strftime("%H:%M")` to `now.strftime("%H%M")`

This way you can convert it to an integer, so you have 1000 instead of 10:00 and you can use addition and subtraction

Answer (score 0):

You can extract hours and minutes from your time using `datetime.hour` and `datetime.minute`.

To get the scaled value you want, for the range you specified (08:00 to 19:00), you can have :

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

if(8 <= now.hour <= 19):
    scaled_time = now.hour - 8
    scaled_time += now.minute / 60
```

Hope it's help.

Edit: you can change 8 and 19 to variables that contain your start and end time, so you can easily modify them

Answer (score 0):

You can divide timedelta objects obtained from subtracting two datetime objects.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> start = datetime(2019, 12, day=19, hour=8, minute=0)
>>> end = datetime(2019, 12, day=19, hour=19, minute=0)
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> print((now - start) / (end - start))
0.7824158481565656
```

Answer (score 0):

8 to 19 is exactly 11 hours, so you don't need to scale it just use current time minus to 8 o'clock. so problem is down to change string to hours in decimal.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

start_time = '08:00'
end_time = '19:00'

def conv(s):
    l = s.split(':')
    h = int(l[0])
    m = int(l[1])
    return h+m/60

st = conv(start_time)
# et = conv(end_time)
n = conv(current_time)

scaled = n-st
print(scaled)
```